# Formatting commas with 2 decimals PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal, text-formatting

I am trying to format a number to have commas and two decimal points at the end of it like: 100,000.00

This is what I have tried, but it won't work because I can't use these number formats on each other because they require a number to be inputted into the format.

```
"{:,}".format("{:.2f}".format(grossPay[i]))
```

So if you have any ideas on how I can do that, I would greatly appreciate it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to format any number into commas for 1000 and 2 decimals, all you need to do in Python is:

```python
"{:,.2f}".format(grossPay[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Format specifiers can be combined:

```
>>> "{:,.2f}".format(100000)
'100,000.00'
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I tried .2f, but not this one. :D